# nginx location empty path

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to define an nginx server configuration as following, but the exact location is never triggered only the general path is triggered. So, the response header is always Access-Control-Allow-Origin. What I want is when I visit "curl -v localhost:8081" it should return me with XYZ header only, because it is exact match, but instead it returns the general one. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
            listen       8081;
            server_name  localhost;
            #index index.html;

            root /usr/share/nginx/wallet;

            location / {
                 try_files $uri /index.html /example.html =404;
                 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            }

            location = / {
               add_header XYZ "xyxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact match location is the first location to process the request, but is not the final location to process the request.

Nginx internally rewrites the URI to `/index.html` and processed this new request in the general location block.

You can force Nginx to process the entire request within the exact match location by adding a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
    add_header XYZ "xyxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}
```